# How to calculate total amperes in two component circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, component-selection

I have two components, a fan and LED strip, that I want to drive with the same power source.  Both the fan and the strip are labeled 12 Volts, So I'm pretty sure I need exactly a 12V DC power source to drive them both.  However, the fan says it requires 0.10 amp and the light strip says it needs 5 amps.  How do I determine what the power source should provide in terms of amperes?  Does that mean I need 5.10 amperes total?  Also there's no Wattage mentioned on the fan but the lights say 5W. Again, how do I choose a single power source for these two components running at the same time?

Comment: The light strip says 5 amps or 5 watts? Voltage * amps = Watts. 12V is what you need. If the LEDs are rated for 5 amps then you'll need 5.1amps total. If they're 5watts, then you'll need 5W/12V+0.1A = Amps_total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the currents simply add when the loads are in parallel.

You need a 12VDC power supply capable of at least 5.1A, I would suggest going a bit higher. There's little harm in using a 10A supply at 5A.

Answer (score 1):

LEDstrips are designed with on strip series R's to run up to 14.2 for rated power e.g. 5W@14.2 but they never tell you this and there may be exceptions.

Fans will have RPM/V ratio as voltage increases speed increases but current stays about same or slow decrease with startup then increase slow with air load profile.

You can drop fan voltage with few diodes and run both off 14.2 or both at reduced power from 12V.  I suspect LED will be ~3W at 12V and 5W at 14.2V. and at their brightest there.